# How can I refresh computed property

Tags: api, vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I want to use recomputed or some other way for followed issue. 
When I save items rendered from `someData`, updated data is sent to the server.
I want to refresh the `someData` so that we can see updated `someData` from the server.
`$recomputed('someData')` is not working.

I think I should use `Promise`, but have no idea how and where I implement that.
I'd appreciate if anyone help me on this issue. Thanks for even minor help.

component:

```
computed : someData : function() { 
  return this.getData()// this is getters in the store 
}
mounted() {
  this.pullData() //this is actions for fetching data in the store, 
  this action commits fetched data to the state for getters
```

Computed property `someData` is used in template.
I want to edit and save `someData`.

store

```
const actions = {
  async pullData(commit){
  await ...// fetch data from apis and commit 
  }
}

const getters = {
  getData : state.data
}
```

also implemented mutation.

This doesn't render `someData`, I mean `someData` is empty once rendered
component.

```
data : { someData : [] },
mounted (){
  this.pullData();
  this.someData = this.getData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pullData` is an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) action, so it already returns a `Promise`. You'd have to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) its result before retrieving it from `getData`:

```js
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  async mounted () {
    await this.pullData()
    this.someData = this.getData
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getData'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['pullData'])
  }
}
```

Comment: @FeiXiao No problem :)